# How to convert the date format from 04-May-2016 to 04/05/2016 using Java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi

I read a .xlsx file and retrieving a date value and it should be entered in to a textbox field.

In excel the cell value is **04/05/2016**.

But while fetching the date value from cell, the value comes as **04-May-2016**.

How do I convert this **04-May-2016 format to mm/dd/yyy**.

**Code:**

```
public static String readExcel(String filePath,String fileName,String sheetName,int RowNumber,int ColNumber) throws Exception{

    Object result = null;
    try
    {

        sheet=getSheet(filePath, fileName, sheetName);
        row=sheet.getRow(RowNumber);

        if(row != null)
        {
            //System.out.println("Row is not empty");
            cell= row.getCell(ColNumber);

            if(cell!=null)
            {
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:// numeric value in excel
                    if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
                        //DateUtil.truncate(new Date(), java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                        result = formatter.format(cell);
                        System.out.println("Today : " + result);    
                    }
                    else{
                        result = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
                    }
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // string value in excel
                    result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: // boolean value in excel
                    result = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK: // blank value in excel
                    result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR: // Error value in excel
                    result = cell.getErrorCellValue()+"";
                    break;


                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //System.out.println("Row is empty");
            return null;
        }

        inputStream.close(); 
    }

    catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    return result.toString();

}
```

**Console:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at utility.ExcelUtility.readExcel(ExcelUtility.java:116)
```

Guide me to reach out.

Comment: why don't you use `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: Yes, I use the **SimpleDateFormat** only and I get the exception as cannot convert the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the date, you can do

```
Date myDate = cell.getDateCellValue()
```

and then use SimpleDateFormat like your example :

```
if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
    Date myDate = cell.getDateCellValue();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String result = formatter.format(myDate);
    System.out.println("Today : " + result);    
}
```

Comment: Why you are not using `myDate` in `result = formatter.format(myDate);`? Instead you are using `cell` which results in `cell.toString()` which results in the same error @Ashok kumar has already.

Comment: My mistake, my point was more on the way of getting the date rather than doing a dateFormat. I'm correcting it.

Comment: @Akah Yeah I understood my mistake. I changed the myDate. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should take date as a string in the file area. My reader like this.

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    cellValue = String.valueOf((long) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;
                }
```

Then you parse string with SimpleDateFormat.

My formatter;

```
public final static DateFormat BIRTHDAY_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("myPatterns");
```

and date;

```
Date date = BIRTHDAY_FORMATTER.parse(myCellValue);
```